# Chef recipe, how to cleanup different directories on different nodes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

We have windows-10 nodes, which have different working directories. So we have to clean up different directories in the nodes. How to write chef recipe in such case?

We have one line powershell command to find these working directories. Also, each node can have multiple working directories. The PS command looks like -

```
> cat .\dir-list.ps1
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\data\ -Recurse -Directory -Filter “delete” | %{$_.FullName.TrimEnd(‘delete’)}
```

When run on a node -

```
> .\dir-list.ps1
C:\data\1\
C:\data\2\
```

On other node list would be different -

```
> .\dir-list.ps1
C:\data\comp\A\
C:\data\comp\B\
C:\data\comp\C\
C:\data\comp\D\
```

Policy is to delete files in above directories which are older than 10 days. Please suggest chef recipe for this case? Should we use attributes on each node? How to iterate through the list of directories returned by above powershell command?

Comment: please specify what did you try so far and why it is not working for you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Here is chef recipe I came up with.
First run the powershell script and redirect the output to a file. File has all the directories to be cleaned. 
Then read the file and run cleanup (from chef supermarket) against all the directories one by one.